# How to load and read excel file in python flask form post api

Tags: python, excel, flask, jinja2

Hi I want to upload a excel file form fronted and in back end i want to read all contents of that Excel File and store that in my database

```
@app.route('/getfile', methods=['POST'])
def getfile():
try:
   file = request.files['file']
   foo=file.filename
   dframe = pd.read_excel(foo)
   return dframe


except Exception as ex:
      return ex
```

i am getting filename and from panda i want to read that excel file data but its showing no such directory exists

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import flask_excel as excel
app = Flask(__name__)
import json
import xlrd
import os 
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict
from pathlib import Path
from flask_cors import CORS,cross_origin
from json import loads
import pandas as pd

wsgi_app = app.wsgi_app
excel.init_excel(app)
```

## code 1

```
@app.route("/upload", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
if request.method == 'POST':
    foo = request.get_array(field_name='file')
    # data = json.dumps(foo, )
    # for i in data[1:]:

     return jsonify({"result":foo })
```

#code 2

```
@app.route('/getfile', methods=['POST'])
def getfile():
try:
   file = request.files['file']
   foo=file.filename
   dframe = pd.read_excel(foo)
   return dframe


except Exception as ex:
      return ex
```

1st code giving me 404 exception and 2nd code giving me "No such Directory exits"
can anybody help me out in this reading the content of excel file

Answer (score 2):

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from tablib import Dataset


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    # I used form data type which means there is a
    # "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    # header in my request
    raw_data = request.files['myfile'].read()  # In form data, I used "myfile" as key.
    dataset = Dataset().load(raw_data)
    return jsonify(dataset.export('json'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This little snippet is working just fine. You don't need to use a huge data analyzing library to import something to database. But if you insist using pandas, your question needs another answer.

Check out the documentation before doing anything else:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/fileuploads/

http://docs.python-tablib.org/en/master/tutorial/#importing-data

Comment: Hi it's working fine when i am sending request from postman i can able to read that Excel file and saving data to database. But when i am trying to send from fronted using java script and j query its still showing 404

Comment: You're posting it wrong obviously. Google "how to post a file with js". You need to show an effort right?

Comment: this code is working fine in windows system ..but when m running same code in Ubuntu or Linux its saying the JSON data must be str not bytes

Comment: @Abhinay , I was testing it in LMDE which is Linux Mint Debian Edition and didn't find anything wrong. Can you elaborate so we can fix it. A traceback would be great.

Comment: when i am running same code in Ubuntu and when i m sending file from postman through windows system then it showing "the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'". same thing is happening when i am sending request from Ubuntu system  also if code is hosted in Ubuntu system

Comment: Dude, this is an encoding error. YOU should debug it and show some effort. For example check the return statement. Check the argument's type that passed to jsonify(). If it's bytes and jsonify() accepts str only, make the argument str for God's sake! That's how this community works. We are not doing the entire job for you. We just help you. Community gives you a hint, a clue, a sample maybe. Debug part is yours. not mine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this buddy, you need to read the file first (`foo.read()`). That way you'll get the un-parsed file, then you need to read this un-parsed file using pandas, like as follows:

```
@app.route('/getfile', methods=['POST'])
def getfile():
try:
    file = request.files['file']
    foo=file.filename
    unparsedFile = foo.read()
    dframe = pd.read_excel(unparsedFile)
    return dframe
except Exception as ex:
    return ex
```